# what is the significance of log retention period in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

If I have log retention period set to 2 hours for a partitions than after 2hrs only the consumed messages will be purged or all the messages whether consumed or not, will be purged?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once the retention hour is over all the messages will be discarded no matter consumed or not. Here is a brief note from the official documentation

> The Kafka cluster retains all published messages—whether or not they have been consumed—for a configurable period of time. **For example if the log retention is set to two days, then for the two days after a message is published it is available for consumption, after which it will be discarded to free up space**. Kafka's performance is effectively constant with respect to data size so retaining lots of data is not a problem.

Comment: I have read it, but couldn't get much out of it. Sentence seems very complicated to me. You made it easy for me, Thanks :)

Comment: In a very simple term once the retention hour is over your queue will be empty .. look at the very last where it says ` Kafka's performance is effectively constant ... problem` .. so you might want to reconsider the retention policy for your application

Comment: Actually two such periods should have been provided. So once the first one expires.. only the consumed messages get purged, and once the second one expires.. all the remaining ones get purged. This would have provided more control.

Comment: it is the responsibility of the consumer to keep track of what has been consumed by them, also the same messages can be consumed by different consumer at same or different time. So saying what has been consumed and what not would be tricky.

Comment: If you need the broker to know if a message has been consumed or not, Kafka is probably not a good fit for you.  You also need to be aware that is possible to consume a message that is older than the retention period as the retention logic is only apply on segment level.  Only closed segment will be removed.  So for low traffic topic/partition some message may stay for a very long time.